# How do I combine 4d array with 2d array into 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays with different dimensions.

```
A.shape 
>> (800, 3, 100, 100)
B.shape
>> (800,)
```

A is a 4d array for images and the structure can be explained as (no. of images, no. of channels, width of images, height of images).
B is a array for labels of the images in A.

I want to combine A and B so that they can be C, which can be:

```
C.shape
>> (800,2)

C[0][0].shape
>> (3,100,100)

type( C[0][1] )
>> <class 'int'>
```

I have tried using  `np.stack, np.vstack, np.hstack, np.concatenate` with different axis, but as A and B have different shape, it didn't work.

How should I combine 2 arrays with different shape to get desired output?

Comment: You can create  a ragged  array but it wouldn't  be as useful since a lot  of  vectorization &  optimization will no  longer apply -

Comment: You can achieve `C.shape = (800, 2, 3, 100, 100)` with broadcasting but it seems useless. If that's for a `for` loop you can do `for a, b in zip(A, B):`

Comment: what's wrong with the list? `c=[A,B]`